# Why is null > 3 false and null < 3 true in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why is null > 3 false and null < 3 true in node?

```
$ node
> null > 3
false
> null < 3
true
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because it coerces `null` to `0` when applying the less/greater than operators.

---

[Section 11.8.5 of the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.5) shows that the `<` and `>` operator will call `ToNumber` on the left value (`null`).

[Section 9.3 of the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3) shows that `ToNumber` will translate `null` to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but it seems like null is 0 when using comparators but oddly null == 0 and null === 0 returns false but null <= 0 returns true when null < 0 returns false.

```
> null == 0 
false
> null === 0
false
> null <= 0
true
> null < 0
false
> null < -1
false
```